# Where is the openerp-server.conf file located on a mac?

Tags: macos, odoo, odoo-9

I installed Odoo 9 community ver. **locally on a Mac**. 
Had many errors while installing it, but finally its up & running. Now I can't find the configuration file to set the port as well as database information. 
The openerp-server.conf file is located in /etc/odoo/ directory on linux. I couldn't find the directory where its saved on mac.

Comment: how did you install it?

Comment: Built from source.

Answer (score 0):

Usually that file is located under debian folder. If you wanna use that configuration file you should do something like

```
./odoo.py --addons-path=<ADDONSPATH> -c debian/openerp-server.conf
```

Or you can change the location of the configuration file